How to calculate the stochastic differential of an exponential term?
I want to calculate $dP(t,T)$, where $P(t,T)=e^{-B(t,T)r(t)+A(t,T)} \tag{1}$ Here, $r(t)$ follows a stochastic process as $dr(t)=\mu(t,r(t))dt + \sigma(t,r(t)dW(t) \tag{2}$ where $W(t)$ is a Brownian Motion.
Here is my attempt:
Let
$$
f(t,X(t)) = e^{X(t)} = e^{-B(t,T)r(t)+A(t,T)} \tag{3}
$$
So,
$$
df(t,X(t)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} dt + \frac{\partial f}{\partial X} dX + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} (dX)^2 \tag{4}
$$
I solved that:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} dt = 0 
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} dX &= e^{-B(t,T)r(t)+A(t,T)} \left(-B(t,T)dr(t) - B_t(t,T)r(t) + A_t(t,T)\right)dX(t) \\
&= e^{-B(t,T)r(t)+A(t,T)} \left(-B(t,T)dr(t) - B_t(t,T)r(t) + A_t(t,T)\right)(B(t,T)(dr(t))\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} (dX)^2 = \frac{1}{2} e^{-B(t,T)r(t)+A(t,T)} \sigma(t)^2 dt \tag{6}
$$
and then I can substitute these all into (4) to get $dP(t,T)$. Is this correct? I do not understand what $dX(t)$ is supposed to be in (5). I wrote that it is $B(t,T)(dr(t)$, but that does not seem right ?

Something is wrong in the equation before (5). In your notation:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}=e^{X(t)},.
$$
But, (integration by-parts aka stochastic product rule) gives:
$$
dX(t)=d\Big{-B(t,T)r(t)+A(t,T)\Big}=-B(t,T),dr(t)- B_t(t,T)r(t),\color{red}{dt}+A_t(t,T)r(t),\color{red}{dt},.
$$

@KurtG. i understand what you mean. I believe I made a msitake in taking it to be $f(t,X(t))$ instead of $f(t,r(t))$. That solved my problem.
